# PHP MySQL same script fail on one

Tags: php, mysql

I made a script for our website that lets us create/view invoices for customers. Works great on my local machine and GoDaddy hosted. When all is said and done the hosted (via GoDaddy) script only works if it is the invoice not the quote script. It gives the old

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'quote(quotedate,customerID,customerName,customerAddr,description,amount,taxdue,t' at line 1"

when I try to insert into the table.

Again, the invoice version works fine and on my local host (win7, webmatrix). The ONLY difference between the two scripts are I have a $matcost $lacost (material/labour cost) in the invoice and $amount (duh?) in quote everything else is the same yet I get the error. If I echo my $sql query it tells me it's not a valid link resource yet all the values have been echoed.

This is the command via quote

```
mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO quote (
        quotedate, 
        customerID, 
        customerName, 
        customerAddr, 
        description, 
        amount, 
        taxdue, 
        totaldue)
    VALUES(
        NOW(), 
        '$billto', 
        '$cust', 
        '$addr', 
        '$desc', 
        '$amount', 
        '$taxdue', 
        '$totaldue')
    ")
    or die(mysql_error());
```

This is the command via invoice

```
mysql_query(
    "INSERT INTO invoice(
        invdate, 
        customerID, 
        customerName, 
        customerAddr, 
        description, 
        material, 
        labour, 
        taxdue, 
        totaldue)
    VALUES(
        NOW(), 
        '$billto', 
        '$cust', 
        '$addr', 
        '$desc', 
        '$matcost', 
        '$labcost', 
        '$taxdue', 
        '$totaldue')") 
    or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: could you please edit your question and make it more readable?

Comment: @user2158506  I updated your post for legibility.  Please read the formatting guide in the future to be kind to the people that are helping you.  You are also able to update your own post to clarify data and add information.

Comment: thank you. I tried to update but the "enter" key does just that, does not new line, it "enters". My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You mention `If I echo my $sql query it tells me it's not a valid link resource` -- that hints you're having trouble connecting to the database, not with the actual query.

Comment: I know I am connecting to the DB as I can pull information (local and hosted) from it and show it. On my localhost everything is fine, I wonder if I'm having an issue with writing to the hosted DB? via the table itself. invoice & quote are in the same table.

Comment: You could try using a classic MySQL client with your credentials and try to insert or update a record. That would rule out the permissions part altogether. Alternatively, write a simple script that just connects and executes a simple query. If that fails, the problem is definently credentials related.

Comment: The "Invoice" table I can show it and INSERT into it no problem, I only get this error when inserting into the "Quote" table in the same DB...

Comment: if you're using MySQL, permissions are per table. please try to run (as an administrative user) a command like `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO ,myuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass'` and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that my Table name of quote was the error. When using PHPMyadmin to run the query it clearly showed my 1064 error and that 'quote' was the issue. Renamed to contract and it's working fine.